# NYTimes iPad app style grid view

Tags: ios, ipad, gridview

Does anyone know how the look of the New York Times iPad app (specifically this view: http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/zdnet-ipad-app-new-york-times.jpg) was achieved?[image: Article selection view]

Essentially, I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for creating something like the above grid with cells that are different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you start with a UIScrollView and then start to re-create all of the work UITableView does for you automatically.

Comment: Ugh. That's what I suspected. I'll hold out for a little while longer, just in case there's someone with a more convenient answer, then I'll accept this. Thanks!

Comment: It's not so bad as it sounds, especially if you don't need cell re-use.  Dynamically creating all of the boxes for text is not too hard.